# Is there a way to expose a cookie's Max-Age attribute (or actual text) using any TNetHTTPClient library or related units?

Tags: delphi, cookies

With the Indy library, I was able to get (what I assume was) the full text of a server side cookie using

**Indy**

```
//where aCookie is TIDCookie
aCookie.ServerCookie
```

Result

```
JSESSIONID=0000R4m1zWweo-8aSDkqoxnrccv:18seb6pc9; Path=/; Domain=somewebsite.com; HttpOnly; Max-Age=251929558529; Expires=Sat, 01-Jan-10000 05:59:59 GMT
```

When trying to convert to TNetHTTPClient, the TCookie attributes only appear to expose Name, Value, Path, Domain, HTTPOnly, Expires, and Secure, according to documentation.  TCookie.ToString returns only the name and value attributes from above.

**NetHTTPClient**

```
//where c is a TCookie.  IHTTPResponse.Cookies and TNetHttpClient.CookieManager.Cookies result in the same values

 CookieText :=  c.Name+'='+c.Value
                +'; Path='+ c.Path
                +'; Domain='+ c.Domain
                +'; HTTPOnly='+ BoolToStr(c.HttpOnly)
                +'; Expires='+FormatDateTime('ddd, dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss',c.Expires)
                +'; Secure='+BoolToStr(c.Secure);
```

Result

```
JSESSIONID=0000q1yBPMF6RpCgOrrOVMEcJfu:18seb6pc9; Path=/; Domain=somewebsite.com; HTTPOnly=-1; Expires=Sat, 30-Dec-1899 00:00:00; Secure=0
```

Is there a way in the NetHTTPClient library to be sure you are seeing all attributes of a *server* cookie?

Comment: `TIdCookie.CookieText` (deprecated by `TIdCookie.ServerCookie`) is server-side, used to send a cookie to a client. `TIdCookie.ClientCookie` and `TCookie.ToString` are client-side, used to send a cookie to a server. `TCookie` does not implement `Max-Age` (I do not know why), but that is allowed by RFC 6265: "*Some existing user agents do not support the Max-Age attribute. User agents that do not support the Max-Age attribute ignore the attribute*", though `Max-Age` is preferred over `Expires`: "*If a cookie has both the Max-Age and the Expires attribute, the Max-Age attribute has precedence*"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I updated my question to reflect that I'm asking about server-side cookies.  Can you please confirm that, while in accordance with RFC 6265, there is no way at this time, to get the entire text of a server-side cookie or a way to have Max-Age exposed by the NetHTTPClient library?

Comment: AFAIK, no method of `TCookie` formats the entire cookie and all of its attributes as a single string, like there is in `TIdCookie`. I suspect this is because all of the `System.Net` stuff is primarily client-side, not server-side (`TIdCookie` is both). As I said earlier, `TCookie` does not appear to implement `Max-Age` at all. `Max-Age` is relative to the date/time when the cookie was issued/stored (which is not an attribute of a cookie itself), whereas `Expires` is absolute. That is probably why `TCookie` does not implement `Max-Age` and prefers `Expires`, even though the RFC allows both.